# Create function string boilerplate

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have ideas for building a javascript framework where yaml or json will be the central building blocks for building frontend apps in a declarative way for sake of maintenance, versioning, automatic documentation, testing, business logic isolation and enforcing transparent structures based on apis.

My idea is having javascript code building blocks generated dynamically based on these yaml / json declarations. However I have trouble finding the best way how to do it.

The options I can think of:

- String manipulations (this would work but seems tedious)
- Learn how to write a transpiler and somehow generate the JS (seems like a long road, but would do it if I had to)
- Creating functions dynamically, but I'm not sure how I would convert them to string.

If you have experience with transpilers or generating Javascript dynamically (in terms of actually outputted syntax), could you give me pointers / advice on what is the best road to take for achieving my goal?

Comment: ES6 Modules and Class for OOP, Proxy, and Reflect APIs for meta.

Comment: @zer00ne What I would like to do is prepare boilerplate files and syntax, so that the programmer can focus on implementation. I'm thinking that I will write my own library based on strings and basic ES6 keywords... unless you could think of something better. Goal is to have some prototype ready in foreseeable time.

Comment: Rendering Strings to DOM is slow and error prone (not so much as was before template literals, nevertheless slow, error prone, and impractical on large scale use. Avoid accessing the DOM as much as possible, if building HTML by Node interface do so using a `document.createDocumentFragment()`

Comment: @zer00ne I'm speaking of filesystem javascript files...

Comment: Do you really need to have generated js files with generated code? Wouldn't something similar to GTM fit your needs? I mean, write some core.js which will define some generic functions which will operate on some *tags*. By *tags* I mean some entity which defines what kind of *thing* it is, e.x. `{type: 'condition', args: [(a<b)], iftrue: fireAction(someAction), iffalse: fireAction(someAction)}`. Did I understood you right? Is that what you need or is it something totally different?

Comment: You know what would be a good improvement for JS file handling is a definitive way to create a base class for the main types of files: ex. text, image, media (audio/video), etc. generically.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Actually yes. The idea of the function boilerplate is to enforce the abstraction of business logic through the setup of a declarative api file that leads to auto-generation of code setup, unit testing and documentation boilerplate. To force the programmer to think of the codebase as a decoupled api and avoid spaghetti code and focus on business continuity within a company when code shifts hands from one programmer to another. The challenge is the generation of the boilerplate which I'm not (yet) familiar with. I'm not really looking for creating new low-level designs.

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, that's also good idea. We actually create base wrappers in our company with SF lightning webcomponents. Would be nice to have a standard.

Comment: @Trace indeed, it would be. Also it would be an excellent feature if a composite/mixin feature was included to use it with ES6 modules.